# jQuery events click and touchstart

Tags: jquery, events, click, touchstart

i was wondering the differences bewteen event click and touchstart? What i know currently is that touchstart is more suited for touchscreens, but click works both on touch actions and mouse clicking. I'm kinda of confused to verify those two, and any of these will cause delay in any situtation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A click is treated like a gesture. It has a delay of around 300ms because the device is waiting to see if the tap is part of a gesture like a double-tap-to-zoom. Touchstart/end has no delay because it is at a lower level than the gestures.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't bind to both as that will trigger twice when used on a touch device. In my current project, I am checking if touchstart exists, and if so assign a var (e.g touchAction = "touchstart") else assign "click" then I can just bind to clickAction and it is optimised for both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any idear which situations are most usable for those two actions? I'm trying to analyze them in a report, need some different idears.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In my code, I use "touchstart" on browsers that support it, and "click" any other browser. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Grezzo That doesn't sound like a good idea, Grezzo. My desktop Chrome 30.x, no touch screen, actually has `window.ontouchstart`, but never fires it. Besides, you might have devices with touch screens (modern notebooks), but the user is still using a mouse.

Comment: @hheimbuerger Fair point. I hadn't considered devices with multiple inputs, or that events would be present even on platforms that don't support them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, click will cause a delay of around 200-300ms if memory serves me correctly. Click essentially waits for a touchstart and then touchend.